# Holomorphic Gauss normal map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces

Let $S$ be a Riemann surface smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Is there necessarily a smooth embedding of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the Gauss normal map $n:S \to S^2$ would be a holomorphic map?Under what conditions on $S$ is the answer affirmative?

The question asks:can we change smoothly the position of a Riemann surface to have a holomorphic Gauss map?

**Note:** The sphere is considered as a Riemann surface with its standard structure

Comment: Critical points of the Gauss map are where the Gaussian curvature of the surface vanishes. I think typically the vanishing locus will be a one-(real)-dimensional subset of the surface. An analytic map has isolated critical points so I think this is unlikely

Comment: @Vik78 thank you. so the first condition we can pose is thst the curvature never vanish example sphere.

Comment: A necessary condition is existence of a metric whose curvature has zero dimensional vanishing locus. Whether such a metric exists is an interesting question in itself

Comment: @Vik78 yes that is very interesting question. BTW in case of identically zero curvature(cylinder)the Gauss map may fail to be holomorphic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gauss map is holomorphic (as a map to the Riemann sphere)
if the surface is minimal. This is Lemma 8.3 in the book of Osserman, A Survey of Minimal Surfaces. In fact, if you replace "embedded" by "immersed" then the converse is also true (see  Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface
scroll down to "Gauss map definition".

Comment: Thank you very much for this iinteresting interpretation in terms of minimal surfaces

Comment: I think the book is “A Survey of Minimal Surfaces”. What Wikipedia article do you mean?

Comment: Also, this paper (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-223/issue-1/Bounds-on-the-topology-and-index-of-minimal-surfaces/10.4310/ACTA.2019.v223.n1.a2.pdf) indicates that there are topological obstructions to a surface having a minimal embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Every orientable surface has a complex structure and an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112538/does-every-orientable-surface-embed-in-mathbbr3), so this should give a negative answer to the noncompact case of the original question

Comment: @Vik78  Thank you very much for very valuable  answers of  both of you which now completly solve my question.

Comment: @Vik78: I had a link to Wikipedia in my answer but somehow it does not show. Now I inserted it again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the embedded surface (assumed compact and not homeomorphic to a sphere) and let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the subsets of $S$ where the Gaussian curvature is positive and negative, respectively. By continuity both sets are open, and both are nonempty ([https://www.math.colostate.edu/~clayton/courses/501/501_9.pdf](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eclayton/courses/501/501_9.pdf)). Let $S’$ be their union. If the vanishing locus of the curvature of $S$ consists of isolated points, then $S’$ is connected, but $S_1$ and $S_2$ give a partition of $S’$ into nonempty open subsets so this is impossible. The vanishing locus of curvature of $S$ is precisely the critical locus of the Gauss map, and since the critical locus of the Gauss map does not consist of isolated points the Gauss map cannot be analytic.

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfect answer in compact case. Is it true that evey open Riemann surface in space admit an embedding with holomorphic Gauss map?

Comment: Right I assumed compactness. For open surfaces it sounds much more complicated. By the same argument you will need a metric of either positive or negative curvature

Comment: but your argument incompact case is very interesting. Thanks again for that. I admit that the non compact case is very general and wide. Howevrr I think that it is unlike that a counter example of non compact csse exist

Comment: for example what can be said about pseudo sphere in space(the space image of Hyperbolic plane)?